# can't concat strings via another string in c

Tags: c, arrays, struct, char, c99

e.g.

```
array = ["abc", "def", "xx"] , concat_string = "-"

output: "abc-def-xx"
```

I got "abc-"

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#ifndef STRUCT_STRING_ARRAY
#define STRUCT_STRING_ARRAY
typedef struct s_string_array
{
    int size;
    char** array;
} string_array;
#endif


char* my_join(string_array* param_1, char* param_2)
{
    int len = param_1->size;
    if(len == 0){
        return NULL;
    }

    char **my_arr = param_1->array;
    int total_len = 0;//this is to create array that will store the entire string , i need total length to know how much malloc to do

    for(int i = 0 ; i < len;i++){
        total_len += strlen(my_arr[i]) + strlen(param_2);
    }

    char *res;
    //char res[total_len];//tried this but it did not work
    for(int i = 0; i < len-1;i++){
        strncat(my_arr[i], param_2, 1);//concat the string- add param_2 to my-arr
        strncat(res, my_arr[i],1); //concat every my_arr to res
    }

    return res;
}


int main(){

    struct s_string_array s= {
        .size = 3,
        .array = (char*[]){"abc", "def", "gh"}

    };

    char *t = "-";

    my_join(&s,t);
    return 0;
}
```

why does it stop at "abc"?

Comment: `char *res;` is an uninitialized pointer that points to no valid memory. `strncat(res, my_arr[i],1); ` invokes *Undefined Behavior* attempting to use it as a destination.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin, hold on but res is my destination, oh u mean res is empty and I copy to empty string thru strncat?

Comment: I mean `res` doesn't point to anything and you attempt to concatenate to the end of an uninitialized pointer. Think of it this way, `char *res;` declares a *pointer to char*, but which char does it point to? It must point to some valid storage capable of storing a character before you can concatenate to that memory location. After it does point to valid storage, `*res = some_char;` is a lot simpler than `strncat(res, my_arr[i],1);`...

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin oh i see, well i just tried malloc - here is my attempt https://repl.it/repls/GrimyOverjoyedScandisk

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin it just prints adg , takes 1 char out of every string...

Comment: Yes allocating memory is a must. You will need to allocate for the sum of the `strlen()` of each of the strings in `.array` plus 2-chars for both `'-'` you want to insert `+1` for the *nul-terminating* character. (at minimum 11-bytes)

Comment: According to the [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strncat). "the dest string must have enough space for the result." Therefore `strncat(res, my_arr[i],1);` won't work as the value of `res` is indeterminate. `strncat(my_arr[i], param_2, 1);` won't work as each element of `my_arr` is a string literal which are illegal to write to. For the first problem `char res[total_len];` should actually work if you're using a recentish c compiler, though for the second you'd need to dynamically allocate the elements of `my_arr` or allocate them with a large size.

Comment: @George i just found the bug , in the 2nd strncat, i only copied 1 char - it should be the length of the entire my_arr[i]! thx u

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix the uninitialized pointer and allocation problem, you can allocate memory for `res` with `malloc()` (don't forget to validate the allocation) and then initialize `res` as an *empty-string*, and adjust your concatenation as follows:

```
char* my_join(string_array* param_1, char* param_2)
{
    int len = param_1->size;
    if(len == 0){
        return NULL;
    }

    char **my_arr = param_1->array;
    int total_len = 0;

    for(int i = 0 ; i < len;i++){       /* if param_2 greater than 1-char, you over-allocate */
        total_len += strlen(my_arr[i]) + strlen(param_2);
    }

    char *res = malloc (total_len);     /* allocate / validate */
    if (!res) {
        perror ("malloc-res");
        return NULL;
    }
    *res = 0;                           /* make res empty-string */

    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        strcat (res, my_arr[i]);        /* concatenate my_arr[i] */
        if (i < len-1)                  /* if not end */
            strcat (res, param_2);      /* concatenate param_2 */
    }

    return res;
}
```

Also note that `strncat(my_arr[i], param_2, 1);` invokes *Undefined Behavior*. You use a *compound* literal to cast to an array of pointers, but the initialization is with *string-literals* -- their contents cannot be changed.